# How to start up this project using the gradle command line?

Tags: gradle

I am following the instruction here https://ktor.io/quickstart/quickstart/gradle.html#intellij-start-a-project to build a simple web server with Netty in Kotlin.

Here is my build.gradle

```
group 'Example'
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    ext.ktor_version = '1.3.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'MainKt'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version"
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

I want to be able to start the server up without using IntelliJ.

I have tried

```
  gradle tasks --all
```

but I cannot find any task that can let me to start up the netty-powered server.

I tried `startScripts` but it complaints about `Deprecated Gradle features`

What is the command line to start up the sever? Or do I need to make further changes to the gradle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You applied and configured the [`application`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) plugin therefore the `run` task is what you're looking for. So:

```
./gradlew run
```

should launch your application.